# React: Is it possible to put a variable in <img src={variable} />

Tags: reactjs, jsx

My **Images.js** file:

`export const LogoDarkText = require('../assets/images/logo-dark-text.png')`

I imported this variable to my *HomePage.js* file

My **HomePage.js** file:

```
import {LogoDarkText} from './Images'

export default function HomePage() {
    return (
           <div>
               <img src={LogoDarkText} />
           </div>
);
}
```

But this is not working. How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the error / HTML output of this react code? If the loader is configured properly and the image is present on the path, this should work.

Comment: it looks like the problem is not in this code but somewhere around. What is the value of LogoDarkText?

Comment: No error! The image not showing

Answer (score 0):

Plz follow the process.

keep your image and static file in the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSkr5.png)"public" folder and import direct.

Comment: I don't want to import direct